# Laravel 5.5 Custom Blade Provider if statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, provider

I would like to make a custom blade provider to clean my code.

```
public function boot() {
    Blade::if ('hasError', function ($field) {
        return session('errors')->has($field);
    });
}
```

This is how i use in view:

```
@hasError('email') has-error @endif
```

But I get this error message:

> Call to a member function has() on null ...

Does anyone have idea?

Comment: If `session('errors')` is `null`, you still try to call `has()` on it. That results in the error you're having. So make sure key `errors` is available in `session()` when calling the `has()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
return session('errors')->has($field);
```

Do this:

```
return session()->has('errors.' . $field);
```

Comment: Thank you dude. This is the best solution. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($validator->fails()) {
   return session()->has('errors.' . $field);
```

You can catch the error on your view using

```
@if ($errors->any())
        {{ implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) }}
@endif
```

UPDATE

To display error under each field you can do like this.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
@if ($errors->has('firstname'))
    <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('firstname') }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: There is no need to copy paste code from my answer. You've posted the answer and then refreshed just one line from my answer.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues I wanted to avoid laravel's default repeating code

Answer (score 0):

This would currently be the same thing as this in the view:

```
@if (session('errors')->has('email'))
 has-error
@endif
```

Using the Blade::if directive, if you want to have this in your view:

```
@hasError('email')
 has-error
@endhasError
```

You should have something like this in your boot method starting in Laravel 5.5:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
public function boot() {

Blade::if('hasError', function ($field) {
    if(session()->has($field){
        /* some validation code 
         if(validation){return true}else{return false;}
        */
    }else{
       return false;
    }
});
```

[Example](https://laravel-news.com/bladeif)

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#custom-if-statements)